# Get defining element from href link

Tags: angular

i have a datatable showing a list of users, i want to be able to click on.

problems i can't use routerLinks inside this datatable but dont want the whole site reloading with a normal HREF.

So depending on what customer i'm clicking i want to be able to send the user to that customer.

This is working for customer 1 but how will i make this dynamic and able to get the ID of the link.

```
this.datatable = (<any>$('#m_datatablegg')).mDatatable(options);   

let _self = this;
this.datatable.on('m-datatable--on-layout-updated', function(e) {
    $(_self.elRef.nativeElement).find('.btn.whatsiteilike ').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        _self.router.navigate(['livedata/customers/1']);
    });
});
```

This is where i'm creating the actual button/link

```
<a href="livedata/customers/'+t.id+'" 
class="m-portlet__nav-link btn whatsiteilike m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--
pill" title="Edit details">
<i class="la la-edit"></i>
</a>
```

This is the reason i got from those making the datatable

> Datatable element is rendered after Angular has finished compiling,
>   render in the browser.
>
> Angular processes the template when the component is compiled. HTML
>   added later via ajax or append is not compiled anymore and RouterLinks
>   bindings are ignored.
>
> You need to add RouterLink programmatically in the component.

Comment: `problems i can't use routerLinks inside this datatable` <= Why not? If you prefer to not handle it in the HTML you could use the `(click)` event and call a method on the component with the identifier or record and the component could make the call to the Router to navigate the user to the customer view. Trying to do 1/2 in javascript and 1/2 in angular is a recipe for bad code and bugs though.

Comment: Reason is added: comming from those making the datatable i'm using.

Comment: See the "Possible duplicate of" link above. You want to do the routing from your component using the `Router` and do that using an exposed method that you could call to from "outside" of the angular framework which means you have to expose it. Call it from a javascript click handler in your .js code.

Comment: Will check it out, thanks for the link.

Comment: Having a hard time understand this, there must be some way to grap the ID of my a or some other way around :/ This thing is way to complicated to be true